# Cloudera Enterprise (Community Edition) for RHEL 8

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager, cloudera-cdp

We are running a mini DWH platform with Cloudera Enterprise community version. Underlying Operating system is RHEL7

Version: Cloudera Express 6.0.1 (#610811 built by jenkins on 20181002-0044 git: c1c9ad537961941820867e39b0a76feb7653f9be)

We have the instructions to upgrade the operating system to RHEL 8.

We are not able to find any upgraded version of Cloudera Enterprise which supports RHEL 8.

Any suggestion on which CDH or CDP version we should refer to have apple to apple match with Cloudera Enterprise and we can upgrade our cluster without many issues.

Note: We want to stay on Community edition of Cloudera.

We tried checking Community site of Cloudera but the information is not very much clear.

Comment: CDH 6.0 went out of support 2 years ago, Community Edition is no longer offered since 2021 due to changes to subscription model. Perhaps you should consider switching to CDP Public Cloud version.

Comment: Thanks, @mazaneicha for the information, CDP Public would need to move out of on-premise to the public cloud? Or is there any way we can set it up on-premise?

CDP is open source and community edition? Or it's purely on a subscription model? Do you mean NO FREE version from 2021?

Comment: No free versions since 2021.